# What would be the mathematical name for a function like the following?

Tags: terminology

x is an independent variable, p is a proportionality constant, and k is a critical value for x.

Let's say:

> 1. f(x)=p (a proportionality constant), where x >= k, a critical value.
> 2. f(x)=0 where x
>
>    The above "p"'s are adjusted to p*, where all the "lost" p values are pro rated among the surviving "p"s.

Example:

In a certain country,

> 1. Political parties receive votes in Congress in proportion, p, to their popular vote totals, unless,
> 2. If a party receives less than 10 percent of the popular vote, the Congressional representation is 0.
> 3. The lost Congressional votes from 2, above, are totalled, and divided pro rata among the surviving parties.